Show rate is very low in Interstitial Ad in flutter google admob
i implemented interstital google admob in my flutter app but problem is my interstitial match rate is 99& but my show rate is 30%. I read all the policiy and make things according to that.
Here is my class
 import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

import '../utils/extensions.dart';

class InterstitialController extends GetxController {
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  RxInt userAdInterval = 3.obs;
  RxInt userLocalClicks = 0.obs;
 
  InterstitialAd? get getInterstitialAd => _interstitialAd;

   

  String get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (kDebugMode) {
       return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
    } else {
      return 'live-id';
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadInterstitialAd() async {
    await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "load");
    print("request sent");
    await InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: interstitialAdUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
          _interstitialAd = ad;
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) async {
          _interstitialAd = null;
          await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "failed");
          debugPrint('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showInterstitialAd() async {
    if (_interstitialAd != null) {
      userLocalClicks++;
      if (userLocalClicks.value >= userAdInterval.value) {
        _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
          onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) async {
            _interstitialAd = null;
            await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "dismissed_full_screen");
          },
          onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) async {
            _interstitialAd = null;
            await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "failed_to_show_full");
          },
        );
        await _interstitialAd!.show();
        print("ad show");
        _interstitialAd = null;
        await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "show");
        await loadInterstitialAd();
        userLocalClicks.value = 0; // Reset clicks after showing ad
      }
    } else {
      await loadInterstitialAd();
      await hitFirebaseEvent(name: "interstitial_ad", from: "ad_not_loaded_yet");
      debugPrint('Interstitial ad has not been loaded yet.');
    }
  }
}


i only call showInterstitialAd() this function on my screen transition
I tried to load only 1 interstitial ad at a time and after show the ad i will load again the ad but my show rate is very low.

I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

@ThanhNguyen No I didn't find a solution for this but I tried to first load and then show the ad simultaneously. it worked after doing this my show rate increased up to 70%
